# Keep log4j2 logs for a week in files with specified size

Tags: logging, log4j2

I'd like to configure log4j2 to keep logs for a week, but each file should have a max size specified.
So it's a combination of `SizebasedTriggeringPolicy` and `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` but in rollover strategy I want to just set for how many days the logs should be kept. I don't care how many files will be created, they just can't be bigger than the specified size and keep logs for a week.
Is it possible to achieve in log4j2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you are describing you only need to use the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy along with a Delete action. See the documentation on the RollingFile Appender for how to do that.

Comment: +10 To be precise: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover